# Como Remover trecho de código usando Find and Replace do Visual Studio com Expressão regular?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Estou com uma aplicação c# que estamos querendo remover trechos de códigos.

Uma das situações que eu tenho diversas If/else, em que o else não faz sentido.

Tipo assim (como exemplo):

```
var entidades= db.Entidades.ToList();
if (!entidades.Where(w => w.ID == 1).Any())
{
     db.Entidades.Add(new Entidade{
         Id = 1,
         Existe = 1,
         Descricao = "Descricao"
     })
}
else 
{
     var entidade = entidades.Where(w => w.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
     entidade.Existe = 1;
     entidade.Descricao = "Descricao";
}
```

E isso acontece em diversas parte do código, muitas mesmo.

Assim gostaria de fazer uma expressão regular que remova todos os else.

Comment: Se tivesse criado uma boa abstração evitaria isto. Leia https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101. Eu odeio RegEx por isso não posso ajudar mais. E existem outros problemas em como as pessoas usam LINQ em EF e ninguém nem percebe.

Comment: Quer utilizar RegEx para remover código? Como assim? Pode dar um exemplo prático, nem que seja em algoritmia, de como pretende fazer isso?

Comment: @Maniero , Acho que não entenderam o que preciso, não estou discutindo a questão de boas praticas no código, quando bati meu olho vi que tinha redundância no código.
A questão é que tenho uma classe com mais de 2000 situações iguais a esse exemplo, e queria automatizar para não ter esse trabalhão todo.

Comment: @JoãoMartins Na ferramenta de Find and Raplaces do Visual Studio, na Aba Replace in Files (Atalho: CTRL + SHIFT + H) tem a opção Use Regular Expression, quero usa-la para remover todos os else.

Comment: Ha, ok, não estava entendendo a questão. Obrigado.

Comment: E qual é o pattern que deseja identificar?